# when Upload file HttpPostedFileBase through ajax mvc returns null

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, jsonresult

I am trying to upload file and some data to a controller action via an AJAX request, however, the HttpPostedFileBase parameter is always null

here is my cshtml

```
<div class="modal fade" id="MyModal">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <a href="#" class="close" data- 
    dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                                <h4 id="ModalTitle"></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                @using (Html.BeginForm("EditResearch", 
    "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form", enctype = "multipart/form- 
    data" }))
                                    {


                                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                                    <fieldset id="SubmitForm">
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ResearchID, 
    new { @id = "ResearchID" })


                                        <div class="input-field">
                                            <label for="name">Journal Name     </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => 
    m.NameJournal, new { @id = "NameJournal", @class = "form-control", 
    @placeholder = "Journal Name*" })
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="input-field">
                                            <label for="name">File</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model =>     model.ResearchFile, new { @type = "file", @name = "ResearchFile", @id
= 
    "ResearchFile" })

                                            @*<input name="fileresearch" 
    id="fileresearch" type="file" />*@
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="input-field">
                                            <label for="name">
                                                Abstract
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => 
    model.ResearchContents, new { @id = "ResearchContents", @class = "form-     control", @onKeyUp = "Count(this,1000)", @onChange = "Count(this,1000)",     placeholder = "Abstract", name = "name", rows
= "6", cols = "85" })
                                        </div>



                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-block 
    btn-danger" id="SaveStudentRecord">Save</a>
                                        </div>

                                    </fieldset>

                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

    $("#SaveStudentRecord").click(function () {
                        var data = $("#SubmitForm").serialize();

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "Post",
                            url: "/Admin/SaveDataInDatabase",
                            data: data,
                            //contentType: false,
                            //processData: false,
                            success: function (result) {

                                if (result) {
                                    alert("Done.");
                                    window.location.href = 
    "/Admin/EditResearch";
                                    $("#MyModal").modal("hide");
                                }
                                else {
                                    alert("Fill Boxes");
                                    //window.location.href = 
    "/Admin/EditResearch";
                                    //$("#MyModal").modal("hide");
                                }



                            }
                        })
                    })
```

---

here is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SaveDataInDatabase(ResearchBL model, 
    HttpPostedFileBase ResearchFile)
        {
            try
            {

                if (Session["user"] != null)
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "";
                    string Err = "";
                    string userID = Session["user"].ToString();

                    ResearchModel researchObj = new ResearchModel();

                    bool Check = researchObj.SaveDataInDatabase(model, 
    userID, ResearchFile, ref Err);

                    ViewBag.Message = Err;

                    return Json(Check, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

                }
                else
                {
                    RedirectToAction("Login", "Admin");
                    return null;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
```

---

here is my class ResearchModel

```
    public Boolean SaveDataInDatabase(ResearchBL model, string userID, 
    HttpPostedFileBase ResearchFile, ref string Err)
            {
                var result = false;

                    using (ZUNew1Entities2 db = new ZUNew1Entities2())
                    {
                        if (model.ResearchID > 0)
                        {

                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ResearcherName)
                            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ResearchName)
                            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.NameJournal)
                            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ResearchContents)
                            && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.VolumeNumber)

                            )
                            {
                                Research research = 
    db.Researches.SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsDeleted == false && x.ResearchID 
    == 
    model.ResearchID);

                                research.ResearchName = model.ResearchName;
                                research.ResearcherName = 
    model.ResearcherName;
                                research.NameJournal = model.NameJournal;
                                research.VolumeNumber = model.VolumeNumber;
                                research.ResearchContents = 
    model.ResearchContents;

                                string day = "01";
                                string cal = model.DateOfPublication + "-" + 
    day;

                                research.DateOfPublication = 
    Convert.ToDateTime(cal);


                                // Update Research File 
    ****************************

                                string File;

                                string uploadFile = 
    "~/UploadFile/Researcher/Files/";

                                if (model.ResearchFile != null)
                                {

                                    var fileName = 
    Path.GetFileName(ResearchFile.FileName);
                                    string pathURL = uploadFile + userID + 
    "_" + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + "_" + 
    DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + 
    "_" + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + 
    DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString() + 
    ".pdf";

                                    var path = 
    Path.Combine(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(pathURL));
                                    ResearchFile.SaveAs(path);


                                }
                                else
                                {

                                    research.ResearchFile = null;

                                }


                                db.Entry(research).State = 
                EntityState.Modified;
                                db.SaveChanges();
                                result = true;
                                Err = "";
                                return true;

                            }
                            else
                            {

                                Err = "Fill Boxes !!";
                                return false;

                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {

                            Err = "";
                            result = false;
                            return false;

                        }
                    }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not done by Ajax use Direct form Submit it will take data.
Write your form under @BeginForm or  tag and use button type to button

Answer (score 0):

I think you can append another fileds of your Form as FormData..

E.g:

```
var files = $("#FileUpload").get(0).files;//file which you are uploading...
            var fileData = new FormData();
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                fileData.append("FileUpload", files[i]);
                fileData.append("DocId", $("#SelectedDocId").val());
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '//',your url i.e/Controller/Action
                dataType: "json",
                autoUpload: false,
                contentType: false, // Not to set any content header
                processData: false, // Not to process data
                data: fileData,
                success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                //Success....
                }
```

and in controller do like this..access the data as Request.Form
    e.g

```
    public ActionResult TempUploadedFiles()
    {

            var DocId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form[0]);
    //and for the uploadedfile
            HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;

            var CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = files[i];
                var FileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.FileName);
            }
     //and write here your saving code..

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should append your file with `FormData`.
This might help you.

```
 var formData = new FormData();        
            var file = document.getElementById("FileUpload").files[0];
            formData.append("Image", file);
      $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("SaveDataInDatabase", "Admin")',
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (resp) {

                    },                
                    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                            alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                            alert('Requested page found. [404]');
                        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                            alert('Internal Server Error [500]');
                        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                            alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                            alert('Time out error.');
                        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                            alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                        } else {
                            alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                        }
                    }
                });
```